# How does cache_digests verify whether a model has changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My understanding (and correct me if I'm wrong) is that in the new cache_digests gem, cache keys for template fragments are created from a combination of an md5 hash of the template itself, template dependencies, and model timestamps.

My question is, how does Rails know if a model has been updated and therefore the cache needs to be invalidated?  It seems Rails would need to access these models in some way to determine if the hash's they generate would be different then what is already in the cache.. if you need to load the models to check, you are gaining little value out of the caching.. clearly I'm missing something.. can you help?

Answer (score 0):

[As the docs say](https://github.com/rails/cache_digests):

> Note that if your application cache is enabled, the template digest will not be recomputed until you restart your application and you will have to restart the app whenever you change template code.

Once you've restarted your app, a call to a fragment with an older MD5 hash will fail, forcing cache reloading of the more recent version.